# pulseaudio: Disable automatic mute

Tags: pulseaudio

My pulseaudio misdetects the audio output. It detects Headphones every now and then, eventhough no headphones are plugged in.

Can I ask Pulseaudio to not automatically mute, if Headphones are plugged in? Maybe a manual way to switch?

The laptop has a single sound card, so it switches between Speaker and Headphones.

"KDE's System Settings > Audio Volume > Automatically switch all running streams when a new output becomes available" sounds like the right thing to disable, but it is already disabled.

Comment: Does the non-muted sound use the same or a different sound card (e.g., HDMI)?